# Update column database using java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am new in programming and i need to update `prix_cdf` which is equals to `prix_usd * rate`. I am able to update the `rate` column but i cannot update the `prix_cdf` column.

Can anyone help me please? Here is my code and my database table:

```java
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       
    String rate = txtrate.getText();
            
    ResultSet rs=Select.getData("select * from menu");
            
    String Query = null;
         
    Query="update menu set rate="+rate+"";
    InsertUpdateDelete.setData(Query, "");
            
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Modifier avec succées!!!");
    setVisible(false);
    new addFoods().setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is my database table - or look at
[image: screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if you are new to programming, why resort to a professional IDE? and why do you think your choice of IDE is relevant here? I hope you understand that this part in your code makes no sense at all? rs.getString("rate*prix_cdf")

Comment: I know this is just an example, but please: Do NEVER add user input to an SQL query by concatenated strings. Always use prepared statements - otherwise you will provide possibility of SQL injections... see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp